# iOS Files.app vs. Samba again: "attribute not found"

Tags: ios, smb, files.app

I don't use the Files.app often, but, when I do, there is usually some problem to deal with first.

My server runs Samba (4.13.17) with the following settings in the `[global]` section:

```
[global]
  client min protocol = NT1
  server min protocol = NT1
  workgroup = XXXXX
  lanman auth = yes
  ntlm auth = yes
  server require schannel:COMPUTER
  unix extensions = yes
  vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
  ea support = yes
  fruit:copyfile = yes
  fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
  fruit:metadata = stream
  fruit:model = MacSamba
  fruit:nfs_aces = no
  fruit:posix_rename = yes
  fruit:veto_appledouble = no
  fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
  fruit:zero_file_id = yes
  readdir_attr:aapl_finder_info = yes
  readdir_attr:aapl_max_access = yes
  readdir_attr:aapl_rsize = yes
```

The Files.app is able to browse the shares, and even create directories. However, when I try to save some pictures into such newly-created directory, I get an error about "attribute not found" (my iPhone talks to me in Ukrainian, so I cannot provide the *exact* error in English here).

The phone's OS is at the latest version available -- is there some new feature I must turn on on the Samba server, perhaps?